# How to setup serial communication in Processing to /dev/rfcomm0

Tags: bluetooth, serial-port, processing, rfcomm

I am trying to perform serial communication on between Ubuntu 12.04 and a JY-MCU bluetooth serial module connected to an Arduino.

I have created this configuration in /etc/bluetooth/rfcomm.conf

```
rfcomm0 {
#   # Automatically bind the device at startup
    bind yes;
#
#   # Bluetooth address of the device    
    device 00:12:11:19:08:54
#   # RFCOMM channel for the connection
    channel 1;
#   # Description of the connection
    comment "Linvor Bluetooth Module";
}
```

I can use putty to communicate with the /dev/rfcomm0 serial port and this works perfectly.

However, despite many attempts I simply cannot see how to create a serial port in Processing that works in any way.

For example :

```
println(Serial.list());
```

prints nothing at all.

If I execute:

```
String portName = "/dev/rfcomm0";
myPort = new Serial(this, portName, 9600);
println(myPort);
```

I see this in the monitor:

```
processing.serial.Serial@1712651
```

But if I then call:

```
 myPort.write('9');
```

I get an exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at processing.serial.Serial.write(Serial.java:572)
    ...
```

I can't understand why this fails. I have been following all the instructions from Tom Igoe's "Making Things Talk", but this just does not work the way he says...

Any help would b great!

Thanks,

Bob

Comment: Can you debug if myPort is really created? Maybe something inside myPort is null and giving the exception when you want to write something.

Also, try to use a terminal on both sides, so you know the connection is set up right. On the arduino side, you could use another linux device if you have that available.

Comment: I am really ignorant in processing... I can communicate with the arduino if I write a routine in python or via putty, but just in processing, which is my goal...

Comment: Seems to be a processing isue then, Iḿ not familiar with that, sadly.
You need sudo/admin rights? I guess it would error earlier if you did.

Comment: I tired that but Sudo/admin rights made no difference... There doesn't seem to be anybody out there who knows about this.  I even wrote to Tom Igoe, because his book gives incorrect instructions regarding serial via rfcomm...

Answer (score 9):

Aftert searching high and low, I have made this work.

The key issue is that processing uses the rxtx java library (RXTX-2.1-7) for serial communications.

The [RXTX wiki](http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Trouble_shooting#How_does_rxtx_detect_ports.3F__Can_I_override_it.3F) says:

> "rxtx tries to detect ports on by scanning /dev for files matching any
>   of a set of known-good prefixes, such as 'ttyS', 'ttym', and since 2.2
>   'ttyUSB' and so on. "

And since the bluetooth device is named  `rfcomm*` it cannot be detected.

The trick is to create a sym link to fool rxtx (use a ttyS device that is not yet assigned):

```
$ sudo ln -s  /dev/rfcomm0 /dev/ttyS99
```

Then, connect:

```
$ sudo rfcomm connect 0
 Connected /dev/rfcomm0 to 00:12:11:19:08:54 on channel 1
 Press CTRL-C for hangup
```

At this point the red led on the JY-MCU becomes solid and processing can detect it:

```
println(Serial.list());
```

output is:

```
[0] "/dev/ttyACM0" 
[1] "/dev/ttyS99"
```

So, serial communication can work.

To summarize, the following process will allow a processing script to communicate via a serial port with a JY-MCU device in a BlueZ linux framework

One time setup:

1. power up the JY-MCU,
2. use the following command to get its hardware address, mine is 00:12:11:19:08:54

   ```
   $ hcitool scan
   ```
3. use that to create the /etc/bluetooth/rfcomm.conf file; you'll note that I chose 0 for the rfcomm device , we need that for connection later:

   ```
   $ cat /etc/bluetooth/rfcomm.conf
   rfcomm0 {
       bind yes;
       device 00:12:11:19:08:54;
       channel    1;
       comment "Linvor Bluetooth Module";
   }
   ```
4. use BlueMan to pair the JY-MCU.

Every time you want to use the JY-MCU

1. create the sym link:

   ```
   $ sudo ln -s  /dev/rfcomm0 /dev/ttyS99
   ```
2. connect to the JY-MCU:

   ```
   $ sudo rfcomm connect 0
     Connected /dev/rfcomm0 to 00:12:11:19:08:54 on channel 1
     Press CTRL-C for hangup
   ```
3. you can now run a processing script and connect to the JY-MCU with
   the code:

   ```
   String portName = "/dev/ttyS99";
   myPort = new Serial(this, portName, 9600);
   ```
4. after running the processing script, be sure to CTRL-C at the
   command line to disconnect the JY-MCU.

That should do it!
Ciao,
Bob

Comment: Thanks, I've followed your steps. I'm able to run the Processing sketch once, then the communication is lost and every time I re-run the program, i gives Port Busy exception. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Just something popped up in my mind.
I had similar problems that were caused due to channel 1 is already used. If you  bind to a channel which already is in use, bad things may happen.

```
sdptool browse local
```

Use that command to see which channels are available on your Ubuntu device.

Comment: Thanks, but that still doesn't help. I can see the rfcomm0 device from Putty, or via the python bluethooth bluez package, but not from processing... I'm pretty sure it's my own ignorance, but see no way forward...